# ¿ Cómo dar permisos para apagar Internet?

Tags: java, android

Estoy con Android Studio.

Tengo una aplicación con varios botones, ¿ Es posible que al pulsar un botón ( mediante permisos de Internet en el Manifest) me desconecte Internet del móvil ?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes deshabilitar (y habilitar) programaticamente WiFi :

```
boolean status = false;

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

Asegura tener el permiso [CHANGE_WIFI_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Para habilitar/deshabilitar la red aquí un método de @Sumam

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {

        try {
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

        }
    }
```

#### Actualización:

Con ayuda de [@RfMvs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/10019/rf-mvs), encontramos que el método anteriormente descrito no funciona desde Android 5.0 ya que el método `setMobileDataEnabled()` fue eliminado del SDK:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setMobileDataEnabled [boolean]

La opción para deshabilitar/habilitar internet es usando este nuevo método, el cual requiere estar dentro de una aplicacion definida como de sistema.

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Method methodSet = null;
    try {
        methodSet = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredMethod("setDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        methodSet.invoke(tm, true);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

El permiso requerido es:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: con eso ultimo de la red, si lo pongo tal cual en el main activity se me irá la red de Internet? Es eso?

Comment: Tu le envias un boolean con valor false para desconectar o True para conectar: setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), false);

Comment: Me he perdido con estas instrucciones, ¿por que te sacas esa instruccion ahora?

Comment: Voy a copiar el código que me has pasado y te comento, por cierto, una vez me salga de la aplicación todo se reseteará y se volvera a conectar Internet o es indefinido hasta que cierre proceso de mi App?

Comment: Te lo digo porque me interesa que también este desconectado Internet incluso cuando me salga de la aplicación, eso es asi¿?

Comment: Si lo desactivas eso aplica para todo el dispositivo, no importa que aplicación lo realizo. Tu tienes que activarlo manualmente o programaticamente con setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), true); pruebalo y comenta tu experiencia.

Comment: Dos cosas Elena, la 1a es que no entiendo donde poner programaticamente lo de "setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), true)" dónde tengo que ponerlo? Y otra, cuando declaro "Field" , cuando importo el método me deja hacerlo como: java.text.Format , java.text.DataFormat, java.text.MessageFormat, java.text.NumberFormat, java.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants o java.lang.reflects, ¿ Cuál le pongo ? Si pongo el primero por ejemplo me fallan otras cosas pero si le pongo otro no.

Comment: Abre chat si quieres que yo no sé, y asi hablamos mejor, he probado ya el codigo pero me salta error cuando aprieto el botón.

Comment: Para apagar usa setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), true); esto puede estar dentro de la ejecución de un botón. y usas estos import import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

Comment: Solo tengo 1 boton y 1 metodo que es el que me has pasado, puedo ponerlo dentro del metodo "private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)" ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46301/discussion-between-elenasys-and-rf-mvs).